# Is there an application that allows me to track changes to the operating system when installing software?

Tags: windows, logging, tracking

For example I need to know the files created by the installation, the registry key entries, system changes, etc. It would be ideal if I could revert the installation. The solution should not be virtualized. It could be a combination of sandboxing e.g. sandboxie however with the ability to view the registry changes, directory and file updates & changes, etc. I used to be able to use Altiris SVS however it is not supported on Windows 7, Windows 2008, etc. The solution should be ideally free.

Comment: A full backup solution is almost guaranteed to be the best 100%, as the number of ways a Setup program can setup and install files is as numerous as there are programs. Then you have to think about files that are overwritten. . .

Comment: @surfasb - Thanks but that doesn't still allow me to track each change that occurs as part of the installation process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I can think of is [Cameyo](http://www.cameyo.com/).
It can be used for creating portable applications. It takes a snapshot before the installation and then after and gives you a package in the end that contains all the files and registry entries that were observed as changed.

What do you mean by "it shouldn't be virtualized"?

[Here](http://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/create-a-portable-version-of-any-application-in-windows/)'s a website that shows step by step process for creating portable programs.

Comment: Thanks. What I meant by not virtualized is that I shouldn't have to run VMWare, VirtualBox, etc to isolate the installation of any application.

Comment: Does Cameyo allow users to view the registry keys, etc or does it simply package them?

Comment: BTW, it's kinda weird way for getting Cameyo .exe file but that's the only way, through cnet's .exe file. There is some kind of virtualization with Cameyo but not in that sense that you mentioned.

Comment: As I understand, you can completely open your package in the end of its process of capturing all the changes.